# Canvas не обновляется при изменение размера окна

Tags: canvas

Пытаюсь заставить холст canvas изменять размер при изменение размеров окна. Нашел функцию на js, чтобы это сделать, но не знаю как вытащить глобальные переменные **W и H** из функции. Без этого ничего не работает.

```
//Создайте холст и инициализируйте контекст
const canvas = document.getElementById("circles");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//Установите размер холста равным размеру карты при измение размера холста
window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);
function resizeCanvas() {
//W и H не работают внутри функции
  const W = canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
  const H = canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;
  draw();
}
resizeCanvas();

//Количество кругов
const circleNbr = 10;

// Градиент
const bgColor1 = 'rgba(153, 83, 85, 1)';
const bgColor2 = 'rgba(52, 9, 80, 1)';

//Создаем массив кругов
let circles = []; 
for(let i = 0; i < circleNbr; i++ ){
  circles.push(new circle());
}

//Функция для создания круга
function circle() {
  //Случайная позиция
  this.x = Math.random()*W;
  this.y = Math.random()*H;

  //Случайная скорость
  this.vx = 0.2 + Math.random()*0.5;
  this.vy = -this.vx;

  //Случайный радиус
  this.r = 3 + Math.random()*10;

  //Случайный цвет непрозрачности
  this.color = "rgba(200, 116, 82,"+(Math.random()*(1 - .5) + .5).toFixed(1)+")";
}

//Функция для рисования градиентного фона с кругами
function draw() {

  const grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, W, H);
  grd.addColorStop(0, bgColor1);
  grd.addColorStop(1, bgColor2);

  //Заполните холст градиентом
  ctx.fillStyle = grd;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);

  //Заполните холст кругами
  for(let j = 0; j < circles.length; j++) {
    let c = circles[j];

    //Круг
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(c.x, c.y, c.r, Math.PI*2, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = c.color;
    ctx.fill();

    //Скорость
    c.x -= c.vx;
    c.y += c.vy;

    //Когда круги выйдут за пределы холста
    if(c.x < -20) c.x = W+20;
    if(c.y < -20) c.y = H+20;
  }
}
setInterval(draw, 30);
```